# LESS & Twitter Bootstrap Not Playing Nice

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

So I am developing a pretty hefty WordPress website where I am using the 320press Twitter Bootstrap theme and I am utilizing LESS CSS.

**Some general info to know:**

- WordPress 3.5
- Bootstrap 2.0
- LESS 1.3.3

Everything has been working alright on the WordPress side, the Bootstrap side, etc.  But...I had a heck of a time getting LESS to work correctly.  I downloaded the less-1.3.3-min.js file from lesscss.org and dropped it in the appropriate folder.  I then referenced it in the header.php file.  I know all of things are correctly linked up because if you View Source on the page and click the less-1.3.3.js reference it loads perfectly.

Here's what the section of code looks like in my header.php file
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/css/fonts.css">`
        `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/css/custom.css">`
        `<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/less/bootstrap.less">`
        `<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/less/responsive.less">`
        `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/js/less-1.3.3-min.js"></script>`

So as instructed on the LESS website I loaded the script after I loaded CSS files.  Things should start happening correct?  No.  So I played around a lot and couldn't figure it out.

[image] <-- Readers text when LESS isn't working

I then found the regular "less-1.3.3.js" file on GIT and downloaded it.  BOOM everything worked.

[image]

[image] <-- this is how it should look (the word "Readers")

Woohoo, victory dance.

Not so fast....

When I shrink my browser down to 979px or under there is a massive gap under the nav.

[image: This gap shouldn't exist]

This gap should be more like this:

[image]

Ok, maybe I messed up some CSS...after about 4 hours of investigating I noticed that the Bootstrap.css file that gets compiled is showing twice.  Once as a linked stylesheet:

[image]

and then again as an embedded stylesheet.

[image]

Using the Web Developer Extension in firefox I delete all of the embedded styles and everything looks great.  But I can't figure out what's dumping that into the site head other than something that the javascript. Does this happen to everybody?

Any ideas? Of course it's an internal-network only development environment so I can't share a URL with you but I have thrown in a few screenshots to show what I'm talking about.

Help me please! My brain is fried trying to find this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: check your functions.php file

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Scott Simpson for the direction here.  I was looking everywhere but the functions.php file which is my first issue.

I commented out the responsive.css in the funcitons.php file and that fixed it.  I knew it was going to be something dumb.

Thank you again.